# Issues with section alignments in HTML

Tags: html, css

I am facing an issue with alignment of sections/columns (I am not sure it's appropriate to call them so but I mean the left/middle/right 33% of the screen) in HTML.
What I see as left column/section is the following:

```html
<div class="single-sidebar">
  <h2 class="sidebar-title">Products</h2>

  <div class="thubmnail-recent">
    <img src="img/Product-thumb-21.jpg" class="recent-thumb" alt="">
    <h2><a href="Product21.html">XXX</a></h2>
    <div class="product-sidebar-price">
      <ins>$29.99</ins>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="single-sidebar">
    <div class="thubmnail-recent">
      <img src="img/Product-thumb-22.jpg" class="recent-thumb" alt="">
      <h2><a href="Product22.html">YYY</a></h2>
      <div class="product-sidebar-price">
        <ins>$29.99</ins>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

When the display is reduced, like on mobile phones, the middle and right columns are shown sequentially after the left one.
For reference, the middle column is the following:

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="product-images">
    
      <div class="product-main-img">
        <img id="primary-img" src="img/Product-thumb-30.jpg" alt="" onclick="window.open(this.src)">
      </div>

      <div class="product-gallery">
        <img id="secondary-img" src="img/Product-thumb-109.jpg" alt="" onclick="window.onclick(this.src)">
        <img id="secondary-img" src="img/Product-thumb-110.jpg" alt="" onclick="window.onclick(this.src)">
      </div>


    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

My problem is that I would like the left column to be displayed on the far right: namely the order of appearance should be from 1), 2), 3) to 2), 3), 1).
As an experiment I have tried to delete the left column/section and I noticed that the middle and right sections of the page don't actually slide leftward but stick in their position, leaving a blank area to the left.
For reference, I also include the associated CSS code for the sections involved:

```css
.sidebar-title {
  color: #fead53;
  font-size: 25px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.single-sidebar {
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.product-main-img {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.product-gallery {
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  margin-left: -15px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Can any of you help me understand how to fix the code so to have the middle and right 33% portions of the screen slide leftward and have the content on the left part shown after the other two sections?
Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: Please bring your code into a normal form for perception.

Comment: I have a hard time to follow your descriptions. Please show the code of all your "columns" together so we can see how you position them. Please shorten it up to the neccessary bits to understand your issue. Are you using bootstrap? You can define the order of CSS flex items. You can use media queries to have an alternative item sequence on small screens.

Comment: This looks like it is using bootstrap - so you should tag this accordingly, and also mention which version you are using. Bootstrap does provides classes to influence column ordering already, https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#grid-column-ordering, https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/columns/#reordering